# Hive date is showing null in elasticsearch

Tags: date, elasticsearch, hive, hue

I have a hive **table details** with below schema

```
name STRING,
address STRING,
dob DATE
```

My dob is stored in yyyy-mm-dd format.like 1988-01-27.

I am trying to load this elastic search table . So i followed below instruction in HUE.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE sampletable (name STRING, address STRING, dob DATE)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsSerDe' 
STORED BY 'org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsStorageHandler' TBLPROPERTIES('es.resource' = 'test4/test4','es.nodes' = 'x.x.x.x:9200');

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE sampletable SELECT * FROM details;

select * from sample table;
```

But DOB field shows NULL for all column. Whereas I can verify that my original hive table has data in date field.

After some research I was able to find that Elasticsearch expects data field to be in yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:zz since my data doesn't match that it throws error. And also it mentioned, I can change the format to "strict_date" format, then it will work fine my hive date format. But I am not sure where in hive query i execute I need to metion this.

Can some one help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

`date` type mapping to hive have some problem .
you can use hive `string` type mapping es `date` type , but you must set the config for hive table for parameter: `es.mapping.date.rich` , set it's value is false . like this **'es.mapping.date.rich' = 'false'** , in create table statement ,it is:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE temp.data_index_es(
id bigint,
userId int,
createTime string
)
STORED BY 'org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES(
'es.nodes' = 'xxxx:9200',
'es.index.auto.create' = 'false',
'es.resource' = 'abc/{_type}',
'es.mapping.date.rich' = 'false',
'es.read.metadata' = 'true',
'es.mapping.id' = 'id',
'es.mapping.names' = 'id:id, userId:userId, createTime:createTime');
```

refer link: [Mapping and Types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/mapping.html)